# Is it possible to have a Power Armor without the helmet?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am customizing dwellers in Fallout Shelter. One of them would look great in a power armor, but with the helmet off.

Is it possible for a dweller to wear power armor without the helmet?

This question also apply to all outfit with headwear, such as the Ninja Outfit or Wasteland Gear.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's not possible.** Unfortunately, you don't get to see their faces when they wear full-on Outfits.